# Crystal Report Can not be displayed when debugging VS 2012 Crystal Report Project

Tags: crystal-reports

I have problem when I am running the Crystal Report VS 2012 project , Report not generating.
But Project running fine without Fail.But Crystal Report Not Displayed in the Browser.
Here My aspx and banckend

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
            <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" AutoDataBind="true"
                            HasToggleParameterPanelButton="False" ToolPanelView="None" 
                                HasCrystalLogo="False" HasToggleGroupTreeButton="False" 
                                PrintMode="ActiveX" />


           <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server" >

           </CR:CrystalReportSource>
       </asp:Panel>
```

`void Page_Intit(object sender,EventArgs e){
            ReportDocument rbtObject = new StockReport();
            DataTable dt = StockController.LoadSearchStock("", "", "");
            rbtObject.SetDataSource(dt);

            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rbtObject;
   }`

Comment: Is Crystal Report viewer not displayed in the page or it's displayed but it's blank?

Comment: Nothing Is Displayed in the page.

Comment: Is this `StockController.LoadSearchStock("", "", "");` populating your `DataTable`?

Comment: Yes It is Populating DataTable.Method Parameters are justt for testing